# Angular service requests paginated collection

Tags: angular

For one of Angular services, the request is:

```
return this.http.get(url)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

For the above, the list of items returned would be limited to the page size set by the backend. e.g.:

```
 [{a:1, b:2}]
```

How do I change the requests to continuously go through paginated collection of items? As in if there is a 'next' with the next page link, it would go on and make another request to get the next batch of data e.g.:

```
 ["next": "https://api.com/endpoints?page=2", results=[{a:1, b:2}]]
```

Comment: can you please show where you using this and how you want try its

Answer (score 0):

You have two solution here ,the first one is to add a new param  to your angular route (page for example) holding the number of the page you are in and access it from your component , the second one is to easily add a static variable tracking the number of the page your are in , and increment it in each request your service made.

Comment: Can you please explain on how to do both using pseudocode?

Comment: @AfeezAziz , for the first solution you can add a new param  to your component route like follow { path: 'path_to_your_compoennt/:page_number',      component: YourComponent }, and access it in your component with route params , after that you pass it to your service to fetch the data regarding the pagination number in your route , hope that i was clear